# Get User Object in Restful Service

Tags: java, restful-authentication

Can anyone please let me know how to get the user object from a request in a Restful service?

Comment: Here is the answer of your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3506039/2105241, The response would have the user object which would be returned from service.

Comment: I want the user from session on the server side, i mean in the actual rest method.

Answer (score 0):

If user has already been authenticated, you can call `request.getRemoteUser()` to get his username.